# Verilog, FPGA, use of an unitialized register

Tags: verilog, fpga, cpu-registers, xilinx, fsm

I have a question about what seems to me odd behavior of an AGC/SPI controller I'm working on.  It's done in Verilog, targeting a Xilinx Spartan 3e FPGA.  The controller is a FSM  that relies on external inputs to start. The state of the FSM is stored in **state_reg** which is not explicitly initialized,  as I thought an uninitialized register would default to zero.  When I implemented the controller the FSM would not run.  Monitoring the SPI bus I observed no activity. To monitor the FSM i routed the **state_reg** to an output bus that went to an LED bank.  That is what the line **assign data_out = state_reg** is doing.  I found though that when I did this the FSM an AGC/SPI controller operated correctly as observed on the SPI bus.  It seems that what is happening is that **state_reg** is in an undetermined state when it initializes and hence the FSM is never in any state so it doesn't run. But by assigning **state_reg** to an output it initialized to **00000000** as I expected it to do from the beginning.  So my question is, is an uninitialized register supposed to assume a value of 0?  By assigning an uninitialized register to an output, does that force it to assume zero as it seemed?  Or is something else going on here that I don't understand?  Below is my code.  I've commented the relevant part where *state_reg** is assigned to **output wire [7:0] data_out**.  I know this is a long question but I"m really trying to understand what type of behavior I should expect.  Thanks.

```
  module agc_control
        (
            input wire [7:0] agc_data,
            input wire clk,
            input wire agc_start,
            input wire AMP_DO,
            output reg MOSI,
            output reg SCK,
            output reg CS_AMP,
            output wire inhibit_ADC,
            output wire [7:0] data_out  
         );

        //signals
        reg [4:0] state_reg,
        reg [2:

0] ampclkreg;
    reg ampclk;
    reg [7:0] agc_data_reg;
    reg agc_running;
    reg [7:0] data_out_reg;
    wire agc_done;




    //ampclk generation
    always @(posedge clk)
        begin
            ampclkreg = ampclkreg + 1;
            if (ampclkreg == 3)
                begin
                    ampclkreg = 0;
                    ampclk = ~ampclk;
                end
        end

    always @(posedge clk)
        begin
            if(agc_start == 1)
                begin
                    agc_running = 1'b1;
                    agc_data_reg = agc_data;
                end
            if(agc_done == 1)
                begin
                    agc_running = 1'b0;
                end
        end



    //FSM
    always @(posedge ampclk)
        begin
            if (agc_running == 0)
                begin
                    SCK = 0;
                    state_reg = 0;
                    CS_AMP = 1;
                end
            if (agc_running == 1)
                begin
                    case (state_reg)
                        0:  begin
                                CS_AMP = 1;
                                SCK = 0;
                                state_reg = 1;
                            end
                        1:  begin
                                CS_AMP = 0;
                                MOSI = agc_data_reg[7];
                                state_reg = 2;
                            end
                        2:  begin
                                SCK = 1;
                                state_reg = 3;
                            end
                        3:  begin
                                SCK = 0;
                                MOSI = agc_data_reg[6];
                                state_reg = 4;
                            end
                        4:  begin
                                SCK = 1;
                                state_reg = 5;
                            end
                        5:  begin
                                SCK = 0;
                                MOSI = agc_data_reg[5];
                                state_reg = 6;
                            end
                        6:  begin
                                SCK = 1;
                                state_reg = 7;
                            end
                        7:  begin
                                SCK = 0;
                                MOSI    = agc_data_reg[4];
                                state_reg = 8;
                            end
                        8:  begin
                                SCK = 1;
                                state_reg = 9;
                            end
                        9:  begin
                                SCK = 0;
                                MOSI = agc_data_reg[3];
                                state_reg = 10;
                            end
                        10:begin
                                SCK = 1;
                                state_reg = 11;
                            end
                        11:begin
                                SCK = 0;
                                MOSI = agc_data_reg[2];
                                state_reg = 12;
                            end
                        12:begin
                                SCK = 1;
                                state_reg = 13;
                            end
                        13:begin
                                SCK = 0;
                                MOSI = agc_data_reg[1];
                                state_reg = 14;
                            end
                        14:begin
                                SCK = 1;
                                state_reg = 15;
                            end
                        15:begin
                                SCK = 0;
                                MOSI = agc_data_reg[0];
                                state_reg = 16;
                            end
                        16:begin
                                SCK = 1;
                                state_reg = 17;
                            end
                        17:begin
                                CS_AMP = 1;
                                state_reg = 18;
                            end
                        18:begin
                                SCK = 0;
                                state_reg = 19;
                            end
                        19:begin
                                state_reg = 19;
                            end
                    default: state_reg = 19;
                endcase
            end
        end

    //retrieve previous vlaues
    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        case(state_reg)
            2: begin
                    if (ampclkreg == 2)             
                        data_out_reg[7] = AMP_DO;
                end
            4: begin
                    if (ampclkreg == 2)
                        data_out_reg[6] = AMP_DO;
                end
            6: begin 
                    if (ampclkreg == 2)
                        data_out_reg[5] = AMP_DO;
                end
            8:  begin
                    if (ampclkreg == 2)
                        data_out_reg[4] = AMP_DO;
                end
            10:begin
                    if (ampclkreg == 2)
                        data_out_reg[3] = AMP_DO;
                end
            12:begin
                    if (ampclkreg == 2)
                        data_out_reg[2] = AMP_DO;
                end
            14:begin
                    if (ampclkreg == 2)
                        data_out_reg[1] = AMP_DO;
                end
            16:begin
                    if (ampclkreg == 2)
                        data_out_reg[0] = AMP_DO;
                end

        endcase
    end


    //output wire [7:0] data_out--to top module to drive 7 LEDs and display state_reg
    assign data_out =  state_reg;

    assign agc_done = (state_reg == 19);
    assign inhibit_ADC = (agc_running == 1);


    endmodule
```

Comment: For FPGA designs, always, always, always initialize your registers.

Comment: Do you get the same odd results when initializing the registers? I am still curious what might be causing this odd behavior - typically if you do not specify, the tools will default to 0 I think.

Answer (score 10):

I answer in the context of FPGAs (I have most experience with Xilinx FPGAs); I disagree with Tim's answer.

When an FPGA is programmed and initialized, *many* internal resources are initialized to a known state. This includes all flip flops and block rams.  By adding blanket reset logic throughout your design, you *may* make it significantly more complicated than it needs to be, if you could otherwise count on internal elements initializing to a known state.  High fanout reset nets can make implementation of your design much more difficult for the router, and mapping your design into slices is also complicated by your choice of resets - especially asynchronous ones.

My suggestions:

- Use initialization values for your registers. Double check Xilinx XST documentation for the version you are using for supported syntax. Contrary to widely held belief, initialization values will be honored in most cases.  The side benefit of doing this, is that the initial state of your chip will match the initial state of your simulation.
- Only reset necessary control signals and leave your datapath registers alone to allow more efficient mapping (for example, a pipeline into a shift register).

Comment: You make a good point, I did not realize that default value was widely supported on FPGA. I let my ASIC experience cloud my judgement :)

Comment: For reference, this is also covered in a Xilinx White paper: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp272.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, is an uninitialized register supposed to assume a
>   value of 0?

**No**, they assume x. For Synthesis you must reset as they may be holding any value. I have no FPGA experience but Nathan Farrington suggests that they are also reset/initialised.

For FPGA doing the following should be enough:

```
reg [4:0] state_reg = 'b0,
```

For Synthesis I would recommend doing this inside a reset clause.

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset) begin
  if (!reset) begin
    state_reg <= 'b0 ;
  end
  else begin
    ..
  end
end
```